# Drupal 7 content empty body

Tags: html, drupal, editor

My drupal 7 website is showing the titles of node only. The content body is saved in database but not showing in page. It is present while edit the node.

As I saw, if I edit the node and save it after changing format = full_html then everything is shown up. But it is not possible to do it for all nodes and comments. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If settings the [text format](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/filter) to "Full HTML" solve the issue, it is probably because a filter of the the previously used text format ("Filtered HTML" I guess) was filtering the whole body content. Likely because the whole content is wrapped in a filtered-out HTML tag. You can edit the text format and review to apply filters to find which one is causing filtering your content bodies at `/admin/config/content/formats`.

Comment: solved it. Thanks a lot. But one problem still here. The images in the body is not showing. They are present in edit mode. If I save the content in full_html, the images show-up. But in filtered_html, no images.

Comment: Again, check the filters for filtered HTML, you may have a filter there that remove your <img> tags. Also, check the source code of the page, if you don't see the image, then likely the <img> tags are missing. If you see the <img> tags, then you have another issue. For instance, you may have a filter that alter the URLs of the images.

Comment: So many thanks. I could not rate you as I have low points. But You saved me.